# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When calling the UserRepository from my UserServiceImpl, I get this error:

"Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.dev.backendproductmanagement.entity.UserEntity'

Any ideas?

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public User saveUser(final User user) {
        final UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.save(user);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(userEntity, User.class);
    }

}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    // findBy -> Username
    Optional<UserEntity> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the `UserService` class declaration? Along with the `User` and `UserEntity` types.

Comment: `UserEntity` != `User`, on the `JpaRepository` you have UserEntity, but you are passing a `User`

Comment: Looks like you're passing an instance of `User` to `userRepository.save(...)` while it expects an instance of `UserEntity`.

Comment: also please don't post code as images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using object mapping like so:

UserServiceImpl:

```
   @Override
    public User saveUser(final User user) {
        final UserEntity userEntity = objectMapper.convertValue(user, UserEntity.class);
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(userEntity, User.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace UserEntity to User in Repository like

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // findBy -> Username
    Optional<UserEntity> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to support *polymorphic* `JpaRepository` types, you have to declare the latter as is:

```
@Repository
public interface UserEntityRepository<T extends UserEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    // findBy -> Username
    Optional<T> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Given above base repository type, you can declare specializations as follows **given `User extends UserEntity`**:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends UserEntityRepository<User> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- look at her in Service:

```
   final UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.save(user);
```

you tell to useRepository to save an object of type "user".

2- But in your Repository you have "UserEntity":

```
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>
```

So change :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>
```

to:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

or the opposite.
change this:

```
 @Override
public User saveUser(final User user) {
    final UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.save(user);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(userEntity, User.class);
}
```

to:

```
 @Override
public userEntitysaveUser(final userEntity user) {
    final UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.save(user);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(userEntity, User.class);
}
```